# Android Floating Action Button null

Tags: android, floating-action-button

In my layout fragment_do_stuff.xml, I have added FloatingActionButton like this

```
<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabDoStuff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/my_fab"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/my_accent"/>
```

In my Fragment, I inflate this view in onCreateView() like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_do_stuff, container, false);

    mDoStuffFab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fabDoStuff);

    return view;
}
```

In my onActivityCreated(), I am setting listener on this FAB like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    mDoStuffFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doStuff();
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

However, howering over the fab mDoStuffFab shows that it is null in both onCreateView and onActivityCreated.  As a result, my app crashes with NullPointerException

What I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post your LogCat snippet with the exception, too?

Comment: `FloatingActionButton` is already part of Android support library, you don't need to use custom. `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake, findViewById was looking for a wrong fab.